# Do I need to rebuild image when parent image is updated?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Assume I have Image1:

```
FROM ubuntu
<...>
```

And Image2:

```
FROM Image1
```

When I do some changed in Image1 do I need to rebuild image2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the updated source image then you need to build again yes. However you can simply continue using your built image (with docker run...).